# C++ Operator Precedence example

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, operator-precedence, evaluation, comma-operator

I am trying to figure out how the following expression is grouped according to precedence:

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
someValue ? ++x, ++y : --x, --y;
```

When someValue is 0 (false) the second part is evaluated, and both x and y become -1. However if someValue is 1 (true) then somehow x becomes 1 but y remains 0, which means the second part of the conditional expression is evaluated too, but only the --y part, which I assume is because of the comma operator, but I can't for the life of me figure out how this is achieved. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`,` has the lowest precedence of all operators, so your expression is parsed as

```
(someValue ? ++x, ++y : --x), --y;
```

Comment: Okay, but what about the first ','? Since ',' has left associativity, why doesn't the left ',' cover the expression until the end?

Comment: Well, if you split at the first comma, you don't get a valid parse.